# Update Table with same table's values

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

i want to update SQL table by adding same table's values.

original table

```
a    |
------
?abc  |  
?def  |
?ghi  |
```

after change,

```
a       |
----------
?a=abc  |  
?a=def  |
?a=ghi  |
```

i want to write a SQL statement to do this.
any help will appreciate.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: yes i tried by adding concatenate and substring methods in SQL. but no luck :(

Comment: i cant understand how it need to mix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Table1.a=REPLACE(Table1.a, '?', '?a=');
```

You could also do this:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Table1.a=CONCAT('?a=',SUBSTRING(Table1.a,2));
```

Or this:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Table1.a=CONCAT('?a=',MID(Table1.a,2))
```

Edit

To address the comment. You could do this:

```
select 
    REPLACE(testStr,CONCAT('&',substring_index(testStr,'&',-1)),'')
FROM
(
    SELECT 'ab&cd&id=123' as testStr
) as tbl
;
```

Reference:

- [CONCAT(str1,str2,...)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)
- [SUBSTRING(str,pos)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring)
- [REPLACE(str,from_str,to_str)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)
- [MID(str,pos,len)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_mid)
- [SUBSTRING_INDEX(str,delim,count)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

Comment: can i take part of value? for ex. if i had ab&cd&id=123  . can i take only ab&cd ? in substring_Index method, its return right side if i used minus values...

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
    REPLACE VIEW view_name AS
    SELECT a
    FROM Table1
    WHERE '?'='?a='
```